# How to create and process queue of data (FIFO) from MS SQL Trigger

Tags: sql-server, trigger, queue

I would like to create a table and fill it with data and have it act as a queue that works in a first-in-first-out fashion. New items can be added at any time while processing or not.

My inserts would look like this

```
INSERT INTO MyQueue
SELECT EmployeeId FROM OtherTable
WHERE EmployeeId NOT IN 
   ( SELECT EmployeeId FROM MyQueue )
```

At the same time there needs to be some mechanism that dequeues the next item and processes a stored procedure passing the latest value. I have a sql trigger that populates the queue.

What would be a good strategy for this mechanism?

The problem I am facing Is that I have the necessity to update some static data when a trigger (parent trigger) is fired. Because, of the nature of the update all the employees in a company need to to be recalculated from the trigger. At the same time the trigger needs to fill in some missing courses that my employees need to be trained in.

When a new course is created it also needs the values to be recalculated but only on a one-to-one basis for that employee. Courses can be created from with in my app or in the parent trigger. So, when the company has to process everything fires twice and with large companies the process can take 10 seconds or more.

Comment: Have you considered service broker for this? Allen White has done several talks about this topic.

Comment: Yes, but the activation procedure isn't working. The procedure needs to be signed, maybe. I guess after a new user is associated with certificate and procedure with the needed permissions, the procedure should be able to respond to the queue receiving messages under that user

Comment: Actually, it wasn't working because of a bug in my activation procedure. Seems to be okay now.